# Rail ActiveRecord get all many to many relations

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have looked through similar questions on here but cant seem to make sense of them.

I have 3 tables `Items`, `Sizes`, and `Item_Sizes` where `Items` has many `Sizes` through `Item_Sizes`.

item.rb:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images

  has_many :category_items
  has_many :categories, through: :category_items

  has_many :item_sizes
  has_many :sizes, through: :item_sizes

  has_many :colour_items
  has_many :colours, through: :colour_items
end
```

size.rb

```
class Size < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :item_sizes
    has_many :items, :through => :item_sizes
end
```

item_size.rb:

```
class ItemSize < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :size
end
```

That all seems to be working. But I'm wondering how to get all `Sizes` that are associated with a subset of items.

I have written a loop to do this but I doubt it's very efficient.

```
def get_all_sizes(items)
    results = []
    items.each do |item|
      item.sizes.each do |size|
        results << size unless results.include?(size)
      end
    end
    
    results
  end
```

Is there a proper query I could use in place of this for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could join the `Item_Sizes` table and get the sizes by the items' ids:

```rb
Size.joins(:item_sizes).where(item_sizes: { item_id: items.ids })
```

Comment: Thanks for that, added `.distinct` to the end. Probably should of clarified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line.

```
result = items.map{|item| item.sizes }.flatten.uniq
```